# How to do the same crop on a batch of photos?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, software-recommendation, picasa

I've got a batch of photos (an owl coughing up a pellet in case you're curious).  I want to make an animated GIF out of them, but the result would be improved if they were all given an identical crop first.

I'm currently using Picasa for my basic photo editing on a Windows 7 PC.  While Picasa does have batch editing, crop is not one of the items on the batch menu.  Does Lightroom have a batch crop?

If there's a way to get Picasa to show me the coordinates of the crop selection rectangle, I could also use that information to do the same crop repeatedly.

Are there any tools that let you crop an animated GIF?  I know I can create the animated GIF by uploading the component images to Google+ and then looking in the Auto Awesome area. I don't know about tools for working with animated GIFs.

Comment: -> [What is the best way to auto crop bulk images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4949/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-crop-bulk-images)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Lightroom has a batch crop.

You first of all apply a crop to the first image. Then in the library grid view, you right-click on the first image, and under the header "Develop Settings" you chose "copy settings".

You then select the option "Crop" and deselect all the other options (unless you also want to copy those to the batch).

You then click on the "copy" button and select all images that you want to apply the crop to. Then right-click again on the images and chose "Develop Settings" - "Paste Settings".

Then the crop is applied to all images selected. [Here is a guide with screenshots](http://visualstate.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/how-to-copy-and-paste-develop-settings-to-multiple-images-in-lightroom/).

Comment: For any Aperture users who stumble across this question, the same feature is available, and is called "Lift Adjustments" and "Stamp Adjustments".

Answer (score 10):

If all your images are of the same size and you want to crop it to the same dimensions, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to get the job done. Take a look at the [Crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) details so as not be surprised by its behaviour :-)

Comment: Thanks; this really helped me; I used this command to crop the images in a directory using this D:\images\img>magick convert -crop 1820x500+50+459 *.png

This was on Windows 10 and I can say that it worked very well and relatively fast

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) (freeware) for batch cropping.

First, get the position and dimensions for the part you want cropped. The easiest way to do this is just open the photo in IrfanView, and drag with the mouse to draw a box on your photo. The title bar will display the size and position of the selected area.

Then go to file menu, and "Batch Conversion/Rename". Select the option for "Batch Conversion", and click "Advanced". This lets you select crop, and specify the position and size. Then select all of your photos, and add them to the list of input files. Then just click "Start batch", and they will all be cropped.

Answer (score 2):

With Adobe Lightroom:

1. Crop the first image
2. Hit **Ctrl-Shift-C** and copy the crop settings
3. Select all pictures and hit **Ctrl-Shift-V**