# How to automatically crop white space from multiple images?

Tags: scanning, cropping

I have recently scanned a bunch of old photo prints to digital for a slide show but all of them have a bunch of white space around them like this: [image: This]

```
                                      /\
                                      ||
                             Unwanted White space
```

I know how to remove the space manually in GIMP but I was wondering if there is some kind of automatic tool to do it for me because I have way too many to do by hand.

Comment: See: [What is the best way to auto crop bulk images?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4949/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-crop-bulk-images)