# Auto crop white border

Tags: cropping

I'm searching for a way to remove the white border of images. I have 6000-7000 images, so I can't do this by hand... Every image has a different size and a different white border. Is there any plugin that does this?

For example:

[image]

has to be:

[image]

Comment: @Crowley Please see: [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge)

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Photoshop has the "Trim" feature. You can automate the process by recording an action, then running it for all the images.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Photoshop, you can do something similar in [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). Use the [**Autocrop Image**](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-autocrop.html) command in [**Batch**](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) mode. Try it on a 'sacrificial' folder first to make sure it works the way you expect.

@Francois at [What is the best way to auto crop bulk images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4949/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-crop-bulk-images) links to [here](http://wp.me/p1YGyn-s9) which has more info about using Gimp for this purpose.

Comment: I tried to autocrop with Gimp and it did work! But I don't understand how to batch this, I don't know anything about programming or anything...

Comment: Click on the highlighted words "Batch" and "What is the best..." for hints on how to batch job the crop.

Comment: So I have to write a script in "Script-Fu - Console"? I can't find out what to write? Can you help me? My images are in the folder C:\Users\virgil2\Desktop\Cataloog copy

Answer (score 1):

I can't offer a plugin (for what?), but the command line image processor [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) offers a `trim` command which is designed to do exactly that.